# Coverity scan - annotation or model to analyse reachability of a certain point in programs

Tags: c, coverity

Given the following program:

```
int main(){
  float x = non_det_float();
  float y = NAN;

  if (isnan(y) && x == 1.0f){
    some_error();
  }
}
```

Let non_det_float() be a function which can return ANY float. (so a nondeterministic float)

Let some_error() be an error which terminates the program.

**Questions:**

1. Is coverity scan able to analyze whether some_error() is reachable or not? or simply able to say "some_error() is dead code" ?
2. Is coverity scan able to simulate non-deterministic floats/doubles or even non deterministic loops ?

If any of this is possible, it would be great to know how. 
Do we have to define a model? Do we have to use some annotations?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is (I think) equivalent to the Halting Problem, and as such is undecidable (i.e., there are always definitions for which it cannot be known whether some_function() gets called or not).

This isn't to say it can't frequently guess or know reliably, but there will of necessity be cases where it cannot.

Comment: Sure, that is correct.

But there are enough tools which are capable of that (at least for the most things), like CBMC, CPAchecker, Smack,..., etc. I want to know if Coverity is able to do what I ask for. ^^ I did not find out how to do it correctly, yet